Is it possible to get the exact requested resource for which a policy gets evaluated in Keycloak?
I want to develop a custom policy provider for Keycloak, that evaluates the decision based on the URI of the requested resource. The resource is /resource/{id}. If the client requests /resource/1 the access should be granted but not if the URI is /resource/2.
I already got a custom policy provider working but I don't know how to extract the requested resource (the string /resource/2) out of the Evaluation Class provided by the Keycloak SPI.
According to the Policy Evaluation API you can fetch the Resource object, but this is contains the resource as it is defined in Keycloak.
My question is now:

Is it possible to the exact requested URI?


To retrieve the exact requested URI in your custom Keycloak policy provider, you can access it through the HttpServletRequest object available within the EvaluationContext provided by the Keycloak SPI.

But the EvaluationContext object does not contain a HttpServletRequest object. You can get a HttpRequest under evaluation.getAuthorizationProvider().getKeycloakSession().getContext().getHttpRequest() but this only returns the request to the Token endpoint. Can you share a documentation or whch package you used?
